# Neo4jclient: Receive event when data changes

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

Is there any way to make the Neo4jclient fire an event when any data inside the database changes?

I know about the "OperationCompleted" event, but it only works if my on application made the change. I would be interested in a solution that also works if a different application on a different computer makes the change.

Any hint would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No, `Neo4jClient` doesn't do that, the client only connects to the server when sending queries, it doesn't keep a connection open. For this to even begin to work - you'd need the database to provide a 'changed' end point - which I guess you *could* do with an unmanaged extension but even then, you'd need to have your own version of the client to hook up to it :/